# Is it possible to access Html from a class without sending as parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I would like to access the `Html` object inside a class, so I could call `Class.Method` to render something using `Html.Partial`.

Is there a way I can call it `Class.Method()` instead of `Class.Method(Html)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another you're going to need a reference to `HtmlHelper` to call the `Partial` method.

You can make it an extension of `HtmlHelper`

```
public static MvcHtmlString Method(this HtmlHelper helper, Class @class)
{
    return helper.Partial(....);
}
```

Or create an `HtmlHelper` from within the `Method` method on `Class`, which might be more problematic since the Context won't exist on that class unless you find a reference to it through your `HttpContext`

You can easily create an HtmlHelper on your Controller like so:

```
    HtmlHelper _htmlHelper;
    public HtmlHelper HtmlHelper
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_htmlHelper == null)
            {
                TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                _htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext,
                    new WebFormView("Default"),
                    new ViewDataDictionary(),
                    new TempDataDictionary(), writer), new ViewPage());
            }

            return _htmlHelper;
        }
    }
```